# Fusion Chart Different plot type for each variable

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

Please if anyone could help me with an example maybe in fiddle or codepen to create (html, JS) [such a graph](https://www.fusioncharts.com/fusiontime/examples/different-plot-type-for-each-variable-measure). The example in the documentation of fusioncharts.com  does not help me much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h5ufs91q/) simplifying the example you provided in the link. Also described in code comment few things.

```
/** Simple steps that may help you to understand easily
1. What schema is?
2. How to provide data
**/

// 3. How to create datatable
const dataStore = new FusionCharts.DataStore();
dataSource.data = dataStore.createDataTable(data, schema);

//4. pass the dataTable in fusionTime configuration to dataSource
new FusionCharts({
  type: "timeseries",
  renderAt: "chart-container",
  width: "100%",
  height: "500",
  dataSource
}).render();
```

To know about schema, data, dataStore and dataTable visit [this link](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusiontime/fusiontime-data-engine/overview).

Comment: Thank you very much @Dip686, I also thank you for the documentation recommendation, I needed it. I wanted to ask you if only the "fusioncharts.js" is needed as a resource and nothing else, because I was reviewing the documentation and a theme is also needed as a resource to be able to display the canvas, but you have done it without that resource

Comment: @conmed, Theme is not a must have requirement, though you can try out them to change the look and feel of the chart.

Comment: One more help @Dip686 please.

I can not find, where to **put the all options** for example to adjust the limits of each series of the axis, enable the thickness, the color of the lines, etc.

I apologize if I bother you.

Comment: You can find out all possible attributes, methods and events exposed for users in fusionCharts dev documentation.  https://fusioncharts.com/dev/

Styling and setting attributes for fusionTime
https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusiontime/fusiontime-attributes

Find here fusionTime related examples https://www.fusioncharts.com/fusiontime/examples

Read about the fusionTime components
https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusiontime/fusiontime-component/time-axis